# Sinatra - Calling a method based on the parameter passed

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have this specific route I want to implement in Sinatra:

```
post '/activate/:model/:id/?' do
model.activate stuff
```

basically what happens here is that I get the model name using `Module.const_get`. I then call the `activate` method on the object. Now I want to add a deactivate method, I can duplicate the code and just modify it to be deactivate, but it's not very DRY-ish. I should probably use a Regex, right? How do I "dynamically call a method" (aka call deactivate or activate depending on the route?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use helpers and object `send` method.

```
module Sinatra
  module ActivateDiactivate
    def activate_diactivate(route)
      activ_deactiv = route.split("/")
      post route do
       model = Module.const_get(activ_deactiv[1].to_sym)
       model.send(method, stuff)
      end
    end
  end
  register AcivateDiactivate
end


activate_diactivate '/activate/:model/:id/?'
activate_diactivate '/diactivate/:model/:id/?'
```